# showing a leak in Iphone +[UIActivityIndicatorView _loadResourcesForStyle:]?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Iphone application in which while i am profiling i am getting a leak in the

> +[UIActivityIndicatorView _loadResourcesForStyle:]in UIkit

But in my application when i search there is no such methode is there.I am using the MBProgressbarHUD class to animate the loading  view.But i want to know where it is happening.Interestingly it is not coming at all time .sometimes only,I really wanted to know the possibilities in which this error can come.can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's definitely happening in or around the use of a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

It looks like the particular line is a private line that you don't have access to but it could be something else close by that is causing it.

Are you using ARC?

If not are you maybe creating a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and then not saving the reference to it in an ivar or not releasing it etc...

Could you provide some code around where you are using the `UIActivityIndicatorView`.